# Updating Google Analytics JavaScript code

Tags: c#, javascript, google-analytics

I've just gotten a Google Analytics project, the first I've ever worked on, and what I want to do is simple. I need to add a line between the 'create' and 'send' portions of the script code that reads ga('require','displayfeatures'). It seems simple but this is the code I have to work with and I have no idea how to edit it:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    try {
        var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-3724234-5");
        //this is where I need to ad the ga('require','displayfeatures') area
        pageTracker._trackPageview();
    } catch (err) { }
</script>
```

I've been able to find some info about ga('something','something') but that is not what is being currently used in the JavaScript above.

Note: None of the code is mind--all of it was created by another programmer who is not available to answer questions about his code.

Any suggestons? I really want to try and get this done quickly--I feel it shouldn't be taking this long!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google analytics code you have, is the old version, where no `ga` 'stuff' is used, it looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Whereas the new analytics code looks like this:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'mydomain.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

As you can see, at the end there are the `ga` statements where you can add yours.

I would recommend upgrading the code, you just have to know and exchange your tracking ID (`UA-XXXXXXXX-X`).

Read more about it here: [Google analytics devguides](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/)

Comment: Ok, I might give this a try. It seems like it would work. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I added a link to the google devguides in my answer, maybe it's helpful to you.

Comment: Ok, your code seems to have worked just fine for me. Thanks again! I was quite lost on what to do.